# How to Fetch Physical Networks in OpenStack using OpenStack4j API

Tags: openstack

I need to Fetch the available Physical networks in Open stack. I am able to fetch using available networks like below.

```
  Set<String> physicalnetworks= new HashSet<String>();
  for (Network network :getOSClinet().networking().network().list();) {
     String phyiscal = network.getProviderPhyNet();
     if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(phyiscal)) {
        physicalnetworks.add(phyiscal );

  }
```

if networks is not available ,i am not able to get the physical network.

Is there any other way to fetch all the physical provider networks?